# Vizrt API JSON Data integration with Graphics

Tags: graphviz

I want to integrate JSON response from API on VIZRT software. Can anyone help me so as how to read the JSON response and display on the graphics or transition...

Thank you on advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and easiest way would be to use the DataPool plugins already provided in most Vizrt installations.  These plugins don't require licensing and are supported in most versions of the software.  There is a plugin titled *DataReader* which allows you to specify a file or web address to pull Excel, SQL, XML, or JSON information from and it can do this on a regular frequency (every 10 seconds, etc).

You can get a lot of info about these plugins on the [documentation site](http://documentation.vizrt.com/datapool-guide/2.13/DataReader.html).

Also, when installing make sure to do a *Complete* installation instead of Typical.  That will make sure that all the DataPool plugins are installed.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would suggest for you to read the necessary sections Vizrt Documentation (It will point you to where you can find example projects etc).

There are many different ways of getting Json Feed to Viz GFX, but it all comes down to your requirements.

If you would like to use Viz Trio you could talk to the Media Sequence Engine of default port 6100 preview and 6800 program.

Or you could also communicate directly to the Viz engine using external Application using  preferably .Net?

```
private void SetValueToDocumentByXPath(XmlDocument doc, string xpath, string value)
{
    var nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
    var it = nav.Select(xpath, nameSpaceManager_);
    if (it.MoveNext())
    {
        it.Current.SetValue(value);
    }
}
```

> SetValueToDocumentByXPath(elementDoc,"//vdf:payload/vdf:field[@name='01']/vdf:value", "My new headline");

The line Above Target Tabfield `01`, Setting its value to `My new headline`.

XMlDocument can be fetch from the MSE.